# UserControl Parent Left

Tags: wpf

So I have a user control within a window. I need to be able (from user control) to retrieve the parent window left and top (in order to locate a new popup I'm opening from the child). I'm trying to do this by referencing the UserControl .Parent property but doesn't seem to work.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using MVVM? Are you concerned about writing code in the code behind? .Net 3.5 or 4.0?

From the UserControl Code behind you could use:

```
Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(userControlReference);



public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(UserControl1_Loaded);

        //Window parrentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);//don't add here the value will be null
    }

    void UserControl1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window parrentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nop, actually I can touch the codebehind but of the user control not the main window.

Comment: Then the edit I just posted should work for you in the code behind of the user control